# Are Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture always in sync?

Tags: .net, cultureinfo, currentuiculture

In a .NET application, it seems you can get or set the current (UI) culture via

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

or via

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

Is one to be preferred over the other? Or is `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` just reading from `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: You might find it instructive to look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs).

Comment: Or even the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx): "This read-only property is equivalent to retrieving the `CultureInfo` object returned by the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property"

Comment: Ok, I was too fast with my question. My apologies. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) for CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture:

> This read-only property is equivalent to retrieving the CultureInfo
>   object returned by the
>   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture property.

so the answer to your second question is definitely yes.

Seeing as they are essentially the same thing, I believe that the choice between them comes down to personal preference, no more.